# What should be minimum width of slit for interference pattern to occur in a single slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, waves

When two slits produce an interference pattern, and one slit is closed, then the interference pattern disappears. Why? As one-slit interference is still possible. What should be the measurements of each slit for this to occur? That is, that, starting with a double slit, closing one slit does not eliminate the interference pattern.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a single slit diffraction produce an interference pattern?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61455/)

Comment: Note that single slit diffraction interference only works for light .... matter waves do not show single slit diffraction interference.